# xkeyval error when compiling with pdfLaTeX

Tags: errors, pdftex, tabularx, xkeyval

**Problem**

I'm using `tabularx` to structure a figure and when I compile the document I get the following error:

```
Package xkeyval Error: `valign' undefined in families `Gin'.
```

**Minimal Working Example (MWE)**

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
  \vspace{3mm}
  \includegraphics[width=.5in, valign=c]{figure8_1_server.eps} & Text.\\
  \vspace{2mm}
  \includegraphics[width=.25in, valign=c]{figure8_1_arrow.eps} & \\
  \vspace{3mm}
  \includegraphics[width=.5in, valign=c]{figure8_1_database.eps} & Text. \\
  \vspace{1mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.25in, valign=c]{figure8_1_arrow.eps} & \\
   \vspace{2mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.5in, valign=c]{figure8_1_table.eps} & Text.\\
   \vspace{0mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.25in, valign=c]{figure8_1_arrow.eps} & \\
   \vspace{2mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.5in, valign=c]{figure8_1_row.eps} & Text.\\
   \vspace{1mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.25in, valign=c]{figure8_1_arrow.eps} & \\
   \vspace{3mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.5in, valign=c]{figure8_1_cell.eps} & Text.
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Text.}
  \label{fig:database}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm getting that error, but I'm also getting a whole bunch of errors because I don't have the graphics...

Comment: I wouldn't call this a minimal example, 90% percent of the packages are irrelevant and you need only one of the graphics. Beside this: valign is an option from the adjustbox package, read its document to learn how to activate it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I removed all other content that use those packages. I wanted to be sure I include all packages in case there is a conflict between them. I assure you that the other packages are being used. Thanks for the tip about the `adjustbox` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

load `adjustbox` before `menukeys` with the option `export`

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{menukeys}
```

### Full Answer

`adjustbox` needs the command `export` to be able to make `\includegraphic` take its commands. This is explained in the documentation, section 2, package options

> ### Adjustbox Documentation Section 2
>
> *export*  – Exports most keys of `\adjustbox` to `\includegraphic`s so that they can be used with this macro as well.

However, adding it here like `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`, causes an error: "Option clash for package adjustbox."

This means that `adjustbox` has likely been loaded twice. LaTeX really doesn't  give many indications of where the package was loaded, so to solve this, we create and [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). That means that we remove(comment out) other packages, like half of them first, typeset and see if the error dissapears. After a few tries, we find that when removing the package `menykeys`, there is no longer an error. In the implementation of `menukeys`, we can see that it loads the package using `\requirepackage{adjustbox}`. We can solve this by loading `adjustbox` with its options before we load `menukeys`. This could also have been solved by passing options to the package in question, but no reason for going into that at the present time.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
  \vspace{3mm}
  \includegraphics[width=.5in, valign=c]{example-image-a} & Text.\\
  \vspace{2mm}
  \includegraphics[width=.25in, valign=c]{example-image-a} & \\
  \vspace{3mm}
  \includegraphics[width=.5in, valign=c]{example-image-a} & Text. \\
  \vspace{1mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.25in, valign=c]{example-image-a} & \\
   \vspace{2mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.5in, valign=c]{example-image-a} & Text.\\
   \vspace{0mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.25in, valign=c]{example-image-a} & \\
   \vspace{2mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.5in, valign=c]{example-image-a} & Text.\\
   \vspace{1mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.25in, valign=c]{example-image-a} & \\
   \vspace{3mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.5in, valign=c]{example-image-a} & Text.
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Text.}
  \label{fig:database}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but it didn't work for some reason. However, moving the option `export` to the documentclass solved all errors.

Comment: I just added more information, and its becouse of the loadorder of `menukeys` and `adjustbox`. I would advice against putting it in the `documentclass`